# How to recover a file just deleted

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, data-recovery

I just deleted a file in Nautilus with Shift+Delete, which warned me that "If you delete an item, it will be permanently lost." I wonder if there is no way to recover the file?

My OS is Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: What kind of fs? ext3? ext4?

Comment: @frabjous: ntfs shared with Windows.

Comment: And [this thread](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/recovering-deleted-files-on-fedora) might help too, since nothing is fedora-specific.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you have to do is to umount the partition.
Next, [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) might help

Answer (score 2):

You restore it from your back up. You do have one of those, right?

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of disk scanners to help you get your files back after you unmount the file system. Try [this](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/) one, a free open source solution just for ext filesystems.

Comment: http://download.cnet.com/NTFS-Undelete/3000-2242_4-145287.html

Answer (score 2):

Check the following links to find some howtos to use popular data recovery tools like **foremost**, **photorec**, **scalpel** and **magic rescue**:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15761/recover-data-like-a-forensics-expert-using-an-ubuntu-live-cd/

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

and finally:

http://technology-flow.com/articles/backtrack-5-complete-tut/forensics/