# How do I simply recover the only file on an empty disk just deleted?

Tags: bash, data-recovery

Usually, the best way to recover a deleted file is to have backups and that, if the backup failed, you should immediately remount the drive read-only. (See this thread: [How to recover a file just deleted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18685/how-to-recover-a-file-just-deleted) )

But in some occasions, if the deleted file wasn't that important, it just would save some time to just "undelete" it.

Is there a simple way I could try on bash for the case that the deleted file on an **ext4 filesystem** was **the only file on the disk**, especially, if the disk is not used otherwise?

Comment: Possibly related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14952/undelete-files-from-local-fileserver

Comment: none of those possible duplicates show a simple solution I am looking for. Maybe it would be easy with `extundelete`?

Comment: That was kind of the conclusion in those Q&A's and others if you search the site. It isn't easy to do this. There are other tools I've seen such as `undelete` floating around the web. They all work some times. But you still needed to understand how the different Unix filesystems work, which defeats the point of what you're asking.

Comment: I was just asking on an ext4 filesystem. I solved it now with extundelete. see my answer below

Comment: I figured you were ext4 but you didn't specify that originally. I believe it's reaching into the journal to do this. Some filesystems don't have a journal so it's trickier. exundelete was one of the tools I was thinking of, glad you solved your issue, good write-up!

Comment: BTW, I didn't suggest this tool b/c if you search this site you'll see countless times where it had problems, so I didn't want to mislead you or others as to it's ability to do this on a consistent basis.

Comment: This question is special, cause it only is safe on a disk you do not use otherwise. no other write actions on that disk. But this is often happening on backup partitions

Comment: I guess, I feel like I've seen this question at least a 1/2 dozen times now, I'm not sure what makes it special as you say.

Answer (score 2):

> **Be aware:**
>   This will only be save if you did not write anything on that
>   disk after you deleted the desired file!

If the deleted file is

```
/media/linuxbak/var/backup/db.tgz
```

then unmount the drive with

```
umount /media/linuxbak
```

change into the directory, you want the recovered file in, for example home:

```
cd ~
```

and restore it (as root) with `extundelete`:

```
apt-get install extundelete
extundelete /dev/sdb2 --restore-file '/var/backup/db.tgz'
```

> WARNING: Extended attributes are not restored. Loading filesystem
>   metadata ... 508 groups loaded. Loading journal descriptors ... 30424
>   descriptors loaded. Restored inode 3591903 to file
>   RECOVERED_FILES/var/backup/db.tgz

(This worked on Ubuntu 13.04)

Comment: Remember to use `sudo` with `umount` and `extundelete` commands