# undelete a just deleted file on ext4 with extundelete

Tags: files, ext4, data-recovery, deleted-files, extundelete

Is there a simple option on `extundelete` how I can try to undelete a file called `/var/tmp/test.iso` that I just deleted?

(it is not so important that I would start to remount the drive read-only or such things. I can also just re-download that file again)

I am looking for a simple command with that I could try if I manage to fast-recover it.

I know, it is possible with remounting the drive **in read-only**: (see [How do I simply recover the only file on an empty disk just deleted?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90186/how-do-i-simply-recover-the-only-file-on-an-empty-disk-just-deleted?rq=1))

But is this also possible somehow **on the still mounted disk?**

---

For info:
if the deleted file is on an NTFS partition it is easy with `ntfsundelete` e.g. if you know the size was about 250MB use

```
sudo ntfsundelete -S 240m-260m -p 100 /dev/hda2
```

and then undelete the file by **inode** e.g. with

```
sudo ntfsundelete /dev/hda2 --undelete --inodes 8270
```

Comment: General question with any utility: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/recovering-accidentally-deleted-files

Comment: That other question is too broad. Here I am looking for a fast insecure solution without much effort (and less chance for success)

Comment: I did not mean to imply duplicate, but you might want to add it to the question why that question was not enough.

Comment: seg fault: "it appears that the **extundelete utility has fallen out of maintenance** and that it requires a version of e2fsprogs that is too old.." https://superuser.com/a/1716473/388883 try Testdisk or Photorec..?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Looking at the usage guide on [extundelete](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/) it seems as though you're limited to undeleting files to a few ways.

#### Restoring all

> extundelete is designed to undelete files from an unmounted partition to a separate (mounted) partition. extundelete will restore any files it finds to a subdirectory of the current directory named “RECOVERED_FILES”. To run the program, type “extundelete --help” to see various options available to you.
>
> Typical usage to restore all deleted files from a partition looks like this:
>
> ```
>     $ extundelete /dev/sda4 --restore-all
> ```

#### Restoring a single file

In addition to this method highlighted in the command line usage:

```
--restore-file path/to/deleted/file
    Attemps to restore the file which was deleted at the given filename, 
    called as "--restore-file dirname/filename".
```

So you should be able to accomplish what you want doing this:

```
$ extundelete --restore-file /var/tmp/test.iso /dev/sda4
```

**NOTE:** In both cases you need to know the device, `/dev/sda4` to perform this command. You'll have to remount the filesystem as readonly. This is one of the conditions of using `extundelete` and there isn't any way around this.

Comment: @rubo77 - correct, there isn't any way around that.

Comment: This actually worked for me an an ext4 filesystem without remounting it read-only. If you try to do it without remounting r/o, then you get a warning which just seems to be telling you that your probability of success is lower if you do that. If it's really super vital to recover the file, then it sounds like you should do that.

Comment: Like @BenCrowell I've used without remount, but program adverts me about data corruption if I continue using hdd... was a recently erase so I just press Enter then get my files back ;)

Comment: extundelete is now unmaintained and segfaults with recent ext4 systems. ext4magic is an alternarive

Answer (score 27):

Typical usage scenario when undeleting *all* files includes need to restore all files deleted from `/dev/sdX1` during approximately last hour:

```
mount -o remount,ro /dev/sdX1
extundelete --restore-all --after $(date -d "-2 hours" +%s) /dev/sdX1
find RECOVERED_FILES/
```

If satisfied with recovered files:

```
mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdX1
```

Comment: mount: you must specify the filesystem type

Comment: remount expects mount point as argument not the device

Comment: @Don'tYouWorryChild `mount -o` takes either dir or device, as per `man mount`

Comment: Instead of subtracting 2 hours from date you can do `$(date -d "-2 hours" +%s)` and the output of `lsblk -p` may be useful to find where that LUKS encrypted LVM cached EXT4 volume is located. ;)

Comment: Note that the target directory will be relative to `$PWD` which I don't think is clearly stated in the manpages.

Comment: Please note that the console output will show only the files that **not** have been restored! I was able to restore two files I removed with `rm`.

Answer (score 10):

extundelete core dumped for me but ext4magic is currently spewing out files:

1. Unmount the filesystem immediately

   - If that means shutting down your computer and attaching your disk to another machine or booting from a live CD, do it
2. Find the partition name with `gparted` or similar
3. You don't need to mount the partition
4. Open a terminal & `sudo su`
5. Install ext4magic: `apt install ext4magic`
6. Create a directory to put the recovered files: `mkdir /mnt/recovered`
7. This will recover all files deleted with a timestamp after 2 hours ago:

   - `sudo ext4magic /dev/sdX# -m -a $(date -d "-2 hours" +%s) -d /mnt/recovered`
     NOTE: This may not mean *deleted* after 2 hours ago. If you have the time and space, it may be better to run the command without the `-a` option and `grep -r` for the content of the file.

Comment: Also, see the gist linked in the other answer for a great description about how to use ext4magic.

Answer (score 7):

extundelete didn't work for me but ext4magic did.

EDIT in 2022:

extundelete hasn't been updated in almost 10 years. If you have a Windows partition, you can try Piriform's [Recuva](https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva). Just don't let Windows format your drive.

Comment: Can you provide an example how to undelete a file

Comment: Until someone can add instructions, this is useful: https://gist.github.com/ebautistabar/cca12863e6335d08a019f015f53fac4a

Comment: I seem to be able to recover a lot more with `extundelete`. But to each her own.