# Recovering a file that is overwritten with cat >

Tags: files, io-redirection, data-recovery, deleted-files

If you have a file called myfile and you do `cat > myfile` instead of `cat myfile` (to see it's contents) I understand that it is overwritten. Is there any possible way to recover its contents? I tried doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, but the file is still overwritten.

Comment: Restore from your regularly updated backup.  That's your best bet.  (Set up a backup before going further, if you haven't already.)  :)

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2677/135943 may help, although there are probably different ways to restore from a *truncated* file (as in this case) rather than a deleted file (as in the question I linked to).  Still, there is no *easy* answer.

Comment: I did exactly the same thing with cat and was sad, but with the link from @Wildcard, specifically the [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2680/188451) was able to recovered it. Remembered first some shorter words then a long hyperlink from the file and out of a massive file which was dredged up was able to find my accidentally overwritten text. If there is a next time, possibly better to not exit after pressing enter if you remember and recover from open file.

Answer (score 7):

As soon as you redirect the stdout of any command to `myfile` with

```
any_command > myfile
```

the system creates `myfile`; if there was another file with the same name, it gets overwritten.

So your best bet is to restore from a backup.

Answer (score 1):

If the process is still holding on to the file you can goto /proc//fd/

then try to cat /proc/pid/fd/filedescriptor and do it.

Take a look at [this](https://www.linux.com/news/bring-back-deleted-files-lsof)

Answer (score 0):

For ext3/ext4 file system maybe is [extundelete.](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/)

But I never use it.

[more explanation here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122305/undelete-a-just-deleted-file-on-ext4-with-extundelete)

Comment: The file wasn't deleted, it was *truncated*. Are you sure an undelete utility can help?

Comment: apparently `extundelete` doesnt work anymore. "it appears that the extundelete utility has fallen out of maintenance and that it requires a version of e2fsprogs that is too old" https://www.unix.com/fedora/279812-segmentation-fault-while-trying-recover-file-extundelete.html