# bash autocompletion resets on every window

Tags: bash, autocomplete

My terminal autocompletion does not work properly when I use root.

`source /etc/bash_completion` works if I invoke that manually.

I need to write above code in every new root terminal to be able to use autocompletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add it to `~/.bashrc`, not bash_profile, in this case... but you'll want to only apply it to interactive shells, to avoid taking time whenever you run a script:

```
case $- in
  *i*) # interactive shell
    source /etc/bash_completion;;
esac
```

You may need to add to `/root/.bashrc` for it to work as root... but why are you running a shell as root instead of using sudo for individual commands?

Comment: Testing `PS1` has nothing to do with interactive shells, actually. Some distributions ship with files that use that, but it's wrong. Interactive shells have `i` in their options in `$-` (even if it wasn't passed explicitly on the command line).

Answer (score 0):

Put this line to `~/.bash_profile`:

`. /etc/bash_completion`

Comment: i had no bash profile, so i created it with your entry. this did not work for me. seems like i could not recover the entire /home/ (I accidently deleted it a few days back: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49080/undo-rm-r-restore-data ). maybe i should just save data and resetup the machine. thanks for your answer thou!