# How to restore EFI partition for Fedora 21

Tags: fedora, uefi

I wiped the EFI partition. How do I restore it without completely reinstalling Fedora?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recovering accidentally deleted files](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/recovering-accidentally-deleted-files)

Comment: First you create a disk image to prevent further damage. Then you create a new ESP and recover the files from the backup.

Comment: @Marco I haven't deleted any documents. "create a new ESP" That is my question: How do I do that?

Comment: Creating an ESP is as simple as creating a new partition, preferably FAT32, and marking it as *active*. But that's not a restore because it doesn't contain any EFI applications, so your system won't boot. The EFI applications are regular files on a file system, nothing fancy about that. That's why I assume this question is a duplicate.