# Running tar cmd in wrong format, how to recover

Tags: files, deleted-files

Trying to tar a file called report, but accidentally running wrong format

```
$ ls -l
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      708 Aug 20 10:12 report
$ tar czvf report report.tar.gz
```

then

```
$ ls -l
-rw-r--r--  1 root root       45 Aug 20 10:13 report
```

how to recover the original file?

Comment: hmm I think you found an interesting way to destroy a file...

Comment: I made a similar mistake on a NTFS drive. Instead of extracting the file, I overwrote it. I was able to recover the original archive using a hex editor.

Comment: I made a similar mistake on a NTFS drive. Instead of extracting the file, I overwrote it. I was able to recover the original archive using a hex editor.

Comment: See also [Recovering accidentally deleted files](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2677/23408).