# How can I change a file to a directory? Files lost after find+mv

Tags: linux, find, command, data-recovery, mv

I had a directory containing some 2000 files.
I ran the following command to move those 2000 files into a target directory:

```
find /opt/alfresco \
        -type f \( -iname \*.pdf -o -iname \*.xml \) \
        -exec mv {} /opt/alfresco/archived/2020-01-07  \; > /opt/alfresco/scripts/move.log
```

But, I forgot to append a `/` at the end of destination path. So what the above command did is, it created a file with name `2020-01-07` and wrote some binary contents to it which is now unreadable. And my 2000 files are gone. This `2020-01-07` file's size is 220 KB. But those 2000 files' size combined was approx 1 GB.

Is there any way I can recover those 2000 files? Or any way by which I can convert this file `2020-01-07` to a directory `2020-01-07` with my data coming back?

Comment: Next time, backup your data. a few gigabytes can fit into a cheap USB key, or on some Internet server (using `scp`, `rsync`, `ftp`, etc...), or some `tar.gz` archive stored elsewhere on your computer

Comment: You might also be interested in using some [version control system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) such as [git](http://git-scm.com/) or [svn](https://subversion.apache.org/). Both can handle `*.pdf` and `*.xml` files quite efficiently. I really suggest taking an hour to learn more about them. In 2020 a few gigabytes of data is not much.

Comment: You could setup some [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) job to backup your small data every hour, e.g. using [rsync(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rsync.1.html)

Comment: A variant on this ("What happens when you run `mv *`?") is a question I've asked in interviews in the past.  Understanding how globs are expanded by the shell, rather than individual commands, and reasoning about the behavior in the way Kusalananda describes are good skills to have if you're working with Linux regularly.

Comment: Getting used with using `mv` (and also `cp`) with options `-i` and `-v` (short `-iv`) has saved me lots of headaches. The  option `-i` instructs `mv` to prompt for confirmation before overwriting existing files and `-v` increases the verbosity by printing the source and the destination paths. Using `-iv` in your case would have paused  the process at the moving of the second file over the first moved and because of the verbosity you would have known which file got moved first.

Comment: Shell commands are little programs. This is why many people test a potentially destructive command first, or at least insert "echo " before the dangerous part to review the output first. Even so, I would have done a cp first, then delete the source files after observing the expected result.

Comment: @andy256: or maybe `ln` to avoid actually copying the data.  Of course I would already have been using `-exec mv -t /dest/dir {} +` so find could pass multiple files to one invocation of `mv`.  It seems `-exec command {} more args +` doesn't work, but apparently does with `{} \;`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Adding a slash at the end of the destination path `/opt/alfresco/archived/2020-01-07` would have made the `mv` command error out, as the `2020-01-07` directory evidently does not exist.  This would have saved your files.

They would also have been saved if `/opt/alfresco/archived/2020-01-07` had been an existing directory (regardless of whether the destination path had a slash at the end or not), and your files would have been moved into that directory (filename collisions may still have been an issue though, as you move files from several directories into a single directory).  This is what you wanted to do.  What you forgot to do was to create that directory first.

Now, since the directory did not exist, what the `find` command did was to take each individual XML and PDF file, rename it to `/opt/alfresco/archived/2020-01-07`, and then continue doing the same with the next file, overwriting the previous.

The file `/opt/alfresco/archived/2020-01-07` is now *the last XML or PDF file found by `find`*.

Also note that since you ran your `find` command across `/opt/alfresco`, any PDF or XML file below that path, for example in any directory beneath `/opt/alfresco/archived`, would have met the same fate.

This is such an easy error to make.
There is no *convenient* way to recover the lost files other than restoring them from your backups.

If you do not take hourly backups of your data, this may be a good point in time to start looking into doing that.  I would recommend `restic` or `borgbackup` for doing backups of personal files, preferably against some sort of off-site or at least external storage.

The following questions and answers may be of some help:

- [Unix/Linux undelete/recover deleted files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80270/unix-linux-undelete-recover-deleted-files)
- [Recovering accidentally deleted files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/recovering-accidentally-deleted-files)
- [And similar questions](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Aunix.stackexchange.com+recover+removed+files)

In your next rewrite of this script, you may want to ignore the `archived` subdirectory, and use `mv -n -t`.  You also need to explicitly `-print` the found files (or use `mv -v`) as `find` will otherwise not output their location:

```sh
find /opt/alfresco \
    -path /opt/alfresco/archived -prune -o \
    -type f \( -iname '*.pdf' -o -iname '*.xml' \) \
    -exec mv -n -t /opt/alfresco/archived/2020-01-07 {} + \
    -print >/opt/alfresco/scripts/move.log
```

---

A few things from the comments (below) that may be useful to know:

- If GNU `mv` is used with `-t target`, it will fail if `target` is not a directory.  You would use `-exec mv -t /opt/alfresco/archived/2020-01-07 {} +` to move multiple files at once with `find` (which would also speed up the operation).
- If GNU `mv` is used with `-n`, it will refuse to overwrite existing files.
- Neither `-t` nor `-n` are standard (macOS and FreeBSD have `-n` too though), but that shouldn't stop you from using them in scripts that don't need to be portable between systems.